# Networking subnetting

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

I have a quick question I'm trying to set up my router DHCP server to have as many leases as possible so I'm trying to change its settings.

At the moment it's set like this:

```
Lan IP address 10.10.0.1
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
DHCP start IP 10.10.0.2
DHCP end IP 10.10.0.254
```

Would it work if I set it up like this?

```
Lan IP address 10.10.0.1
Subnet Mask 255.255.248.0
DHCP start IP 10.10.0.2
DHCP end IP 10.10.7.254
```

And would it be able to give out IP's after that let's say like `10.10.5.25`?

Or how could I get it to give out more addresses automatically?

The router is a zxhn h298a so I don't have many options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it work if I set it up like this?

> ```
> Lan IP address 10.10.0.1 
> subnet mask 255.255.248.0 
> DHCP start IP 10.10.0.2 
> DHCP end IP 10.10.7.254
> ```

yes, this will work

> And would it be able to give out IP's after that let's say like 10.10.5.25?

Yes, you can give it out

> Or how could I get it to give out more addresses automatically?

There are two options:

- To give out more addresses automatically you need to "lower" the subnet mask and change it from `255.255.248.0` to e.g. `255.255.240.0`. With `255.255.248.0` you can assign 2046 hosts, with `255.255.240.0` you can assign 4094 hosts.
- If your router does not support more hosts you could disable the DHCP in the router and setup a new DHCP on a PC connected to your network.